# "Smaller" math proofs discovered as a means to prove a more substantial theorem

Tags: soft-question, math-history

I know the title may not be fully descriptive, but please bear with me.

When I do math, whether I have formed a conjecture and seek to prove it or am simply proving nontrivial theorems for homework assignments, I will in some cases look for "intermediate" steps, so to speak. For example, if I know that $A \Rightarrow B$, $B \Rightarrow C$, and $C \Rightarrow D$, then proving $A \Rightarrow D$ simply amounts to wisely choosing these intermediate steps to get the result.

What I am interested in is the opposite. For example, if a mathematician was attempting to prove $A \Rightarrow D$, and he/she also knew that $A \Rightarrow B$ and $C \Rightarrow D$, that person may attempt to prove that $B \Rightarrow C$ to complete the proof. Are there any historical examples of a situation like this where $B \Rightarrow C$ had never previously been rigorously proven, but was eventually shown to be true as a result of someone's attempt to prove $A \Rightarrow D$?

I apologize for the soft question, but I was just thinking about *how* I do math one day, and in almost every case I can think of, I am using these "smaller" results as building blocks to a larger proof, which seems generally logical. Even in textbooks, almost every result is presented this way because it makes the most sense for students understand the pieces of a proof before they can understand the whole thing. However, it would not surprise me if researchers grappling with open questions have taken the approach I described here, so I am curious if there are any noteworthy results that were discovered this way.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but wasn't this the case with FLT? Didn't Wiles prove something that implied that the theorem holds?

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek Not quite, it was something like $A\implies B$ and $B\implies C$. I did not quite understand the details, but the prove contained essentially of two steps (of course both steps were extremely difficult)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this happens a lot. Ramsey's theorem was originally just a minor lemma for a paper where Ramsey was trying to prove something else.

Comment: I would guess that solving the "small steps" in order to prove the big theorem is almost always how math is done.

Comment: I think it would be harder to find an example of something where all the significant small steps existed before the major result.

Comment: Right, I would imagine that not all the steps usually exist. This was my main motivation for asking the question. But I'm making a distinction between "a true mathematical statement" and "a historically significant mathematical result"

Comment: The chronological order of a discovery seems usually different than a logical order (or a rearrangement) of the discovery. You may try MathOverflow to get a better chance to solicit the answers you are after. :)

Comment: Not totally on point, but this post reminds me of a write-up from Terry Tao about progress on a major result, [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/be-sceptical-of-your-own-work/). The relevant part is steps 1-23 at the end.